# Create Facebook Events Outside of the Main Facebook Site

Tags: facebook

Say I have a business website for a restaurant and a customer books a table for a large group. Is there a way I could include as part of the booking process a chance for the customer to create a facebook event from the restaurants site. I know the customer would in some way have to log on to facebook from the restaurant site, but could the event have some details already filled in for example where the event takes place, the time and the picture for the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, here is the [link to the api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/). But remember that this api call

> Requires the create_event permission.

So you will need to ask user for permission to create an event in his account.

Comment: Unfortunately this options seems to have been removed since API 2.0...is there a way to create an event from a homepage in some other way?

Comment: @broch according to the documentation, there is no way to create events in the graph v2.0. You can try to use v1.0 on your own risk as people suggest [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102413/creating-facebook-event-graph-api)

Comment: Thanks Igor, I think it will also be impossible with the v1.0 api since it is deprecated end of April this year. Too bad, it could have been a neat extension to my website.