# Creating Facebook Event - Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have gotten the access token with the correct permissions to manage events etc. However, the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{pageID}/events?access_token=xxxx&name%3Dtest%26description%3Dtest%2520description
```

(I have not included the credentials here)

Upon testing the above does not create a name value or description for the event - the page just returns a blank data object.

Is it possible to create some test data for an event through the browser address bar and if so what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Are you making that as a GET or POST request?

Comment: I'm struggling with this, too. It seems, you cannot create events via the graph API anymore. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event says: "You cannot create events via the Graph API.". Does anyone know how to create events?

Comment: i'm wondering the same thing, here.

Answer (score 11):

As per Facebook's documentation in: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event#publish

> **Publishing**
>
> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

Use Facebook SDK instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api

Comment: How would the Facebook SDK help?

Comment: You can still create events using JavaScript SDK but this functionality has been deprecated in version 2. You can still use API version 1, but end of life for this version is sometime march-april next year.

Comment: Is this still current?

Comment: As of today's date, it's not possible to create events anymore

Comment: This answer is now outdated. The suggested link displays the Graph API page.

Answer (score 11):

I spent a long time battling this too.

**TL;DR - graph v1.0 allows event creation, graph v2.0 does not.**

Facebook [Graph API 1.0 "events"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/event) allows you to create events (all CRUD actions) and is fully described in the docs. [Graph version 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event) does not allow you to CRUD event data. This is where the other answer came from.

Graph version 1.0 will be depricated April 30, 2015 ([official changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)).